# Mocking a function return value called from main() in unit test

Tags: go, mocking, aws-secrets-manager

In `main.go`, I have some code that makes a network call to AWS Secrets manager.

```golang
func main() {
    secretName := os.Getenv("DYNAMO_SECRET")
    credentials, err := getSecret(secretName)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Errorf("Failed to retrieve secret from AWS Secrets manager %+v\n", err)
        panic(err)
    }
    router, err := setupRouter(credentials)
```

The `getSecret(secretName)` function makes a network call to AWS Secrets manager underneath the hood. In my unit test for `main`, I have the code below.

```golang
func TestMainProgram(t *testing.T) {
    defer mockStartServer(nil)()
    defer mockSetupRouter(mux.NewRouter(), nil)()
    main()
    t.Log("Everything is perfect.")
}
```

When running my unit test, I want to mock the network call to AWS Secrets Manager. Is it possible to mock the return value of `getSecret(secretName)`? In a Java context, I'm trying to do something similar using `Mockito` and the `when(functionIsCalled).thenReturn(mockValue)` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function variable to set it to some other value for testing:

```
func defaultGetSecret(secretName string) (Credentials, error) {...}

var getSecret=defaultGetSecret

func main() {
   ...
   credentials, err:=getSecret(...)
}
```

In your tests, you can change `getSecret` to point to something else:

```
func TestMain(t *testing.T) {
   getSecret=func(secretName string) (Credentials,error) {
      return mockCredentials,nil
   }
   main()
}
```

Comment: Adding
```getSecret=func(secretName string) (Credentials,error) {
      return nil,nil
}```

gives me `undefined: getSecret`

Comment: Did you declare the `getSecret` variable? Is your test is `main` package?

Comment: You declared getSecret in main. Declare it outside. I edited the answer to illustrate